# How to change image permission (AMI) for AWS using boto/python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

How can we change an AMI's permission to add more AWS accounts using python's boto module ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [modify_image_attribute](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.modify_image_attribute) method of the `boto.ec2` module to modify this and other attributes associated with an image.

You can add additional authorized users like this:

```
import boto.ec2

ec2 = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('<your region>')
ec2.modify_image_attribute('ami-12345678', operation='add', attribute='launchPermission', user_ids=['user_id_1', 'user_id_2'])
```

Similarly, you could add authorize groups using the `attribute='launchPermission'` and the group values in the parameter `group_ids`.

Comment: Fails with `TypeError: modify_image_attribute() only accepts keyword arguments.`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `boto3` way of doing it:

```py
    import boto3 

    ec2 = boto3.client("ec2")

    ACCOUNTS = [
        "123456789012",
        "123456789013",
    ]

    ec2.modify_image_attribute(
        Attribute='launchPermission',
        ImageId='ami-abc123',
        OperationType='add',
        UserIds=ACCOUNTS
    )
```

There are ways to also add/remove users/groups at the same time, [see the docs for more details](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_image_attribute) and examples of other use cases.